# Lie derivative of Dirac distribution

Tags: differential-geometry, dirac-delta, lie-derivative

I am trying to prove a result regarding the Lie derivative of the Dirac distribution, whose support would be an integral curve of the Killing vector. I expect it to be zero, because this delta distribution would be an object completely characterised by the Killing vector itself.

In particular, let $k^a$ be a Killing vector on a given manifold, $x^\alpha$ a chart of coordinates and let $\mathcal{C}$ be an integral curve of $k^a$, which we will parametrise by a set of four equations $x^\alpha=z^\alpha(\tau)$, with $\tau$ the propertime along $\mathcal{C}$. 
Let now $\delta_4(x^\alpha-z^\alpha(\tau))$ be the covariant Dirac delta whose support is thus $\mathcal{C}$. Do we have $\mathcal{L}_k \delta_4$ = 0 ? And if so, any idea as to how it could be proven ?

Many thanks

Hypaulite

Comment: Differential operators acting on distributions are defined essentially by demanding that the integration by parts formula holds after smearing with a test function. Have you tried to compute the derivative directly from this definition?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem is that here, I am trying to obtain a result like $\int_{\mathbb{R}} F(\tau) \mathcal{L}_k \delta_4 d\tau =0$, independantly of the function $F$ defined along $\mathcal{C}$. Imposing that it should verify the IbP formula would not lead me anywhere I think..

Comment: The first issue here is that it is unclear whether the distribution you have in mind is well-defined. Consider for example the torus with the standard flat metric. There exist Killing vector fields whose integral curves are dense (can you construct an example?). Moreover they visit every open subset of the torus infinitely many times. Thus it seems unlikely that you can make sense of integrals over these curves - they would be infinite.

Comment: Heuristically, your result expected result is plausible because $\mathcal L_k$ is the derivative in the direction of $k$. Integrating that over a flow-line of $k$ you would get an integral of a derivative. Boundary term could be neglected for example if $C$ eventually leaves every compact set or if it is closed. However before you can make this precise, you need to define your distribution properly. That is you need to write down a manifestly well-defined expression for $F(\phi)$, where $\phi$ is a test function.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to write all things nicely and think about your example with the torus. Since this is my first MSE thread, I don't know if I can come back later here to add to my initial question, I'll see in a few days. Thks again !

Comment: Here is my computation. Since $\mathcal{L}_k \delta_4$ is the Lie derivative of a scalar field, we have $\mathcal{L}_k \delta_4 = k^e \nabla_e \delta_4 = \frac{d\delta_4}{d\lambda}$, where $\lambda$ is the parameter associated to $k^e$. Introducing the proper time we can write $\frac{d\delta_4}{d\lambda} = \frac{d\tau}{d\lambda} \frac{d\delta_4}{d\tau}$. Hence $\int T(\tau) \mathcal{L}_k \delta_4 d\tau = \int T(\tau) \frac{d\tau}{d\lambda} \frac{d\delta_4}{d\tau} d\tau$. Now integrating by parts gives $-\int \frac{d}{d\tau} (T(\tau) \frac{d\tau}{d\lambda}) \delta_4 d\tau$ (1/2)

Comment: In my computation, $T(\tau)$ is a tensor defined along the curve. Do you agree with all this ? If so then we have an answer : the $\mathcal{L}_k(\delta_4)$ operator acts as a derivative in the direction of $k^e$ and and a simple $\delta_3$ function in spatial directions...